# The match that begins earliest wins?

Tags: regex, r

I was told that regex obey this rule:  the match that begins earliest wins.

```
> aab <- "aab"
> gsub("a.*?b", "", aab, perl=T)
[1] ""
> gsub("a.*b", "", aab, perl=T)
[1] ""
```

For now, it seems that the rule is obeyed, but...

```
> aab <- "\na\nab"
> gsub("\n.*?b", "", aab, perl=T)
[1] "\na"
> gsub("\n.*b", "",aab, perl=T)
[1] "\na"
```

Why does it disobey now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `.`, by default, means "any character other than newline"; so the full string `\na\nab` actually can't match `\n.*b` (since the `\n` in the middle isn't matched by `.`). The only part that matches it is the substring `\nab`.

To change `.` to mean "any character at all, even newline", you can insert the magic sequence `(?s)` earlier in the pattern:

```
gsub("(?s)\n.*?b", "", aab, perl=T)
```

to turn on the `s` option (indicating "single-line" mode, though the name is misleading: its only effect is to change the meaning of `.` in this way).